# Link-to cannot find nested resource on passing two models

Tags: ember.js

Here is the app i am learning to build.

categories has many products.

Accordion of category - heading and products as body is in categories template
router.js

```
MyApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('categories', {path: '/'}, function () {
        this.resource('category', { path: '/:category_id'}, function () {
            this.resource('product', {
                path: '/:product_id'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

My categories handlebar

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
   {{#each category in model}}
     {{view MyApp.AccordionView  context=category}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

and my accordion view

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    {{#view MyApp.AccordionTitleView }}{{name}} {{/view}} 
  </h4>
</div>
<div {{bind-attr id=id}}class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      {{#each products itemController="product"}}
        <tr><td>{{#link-to 'category.product' category content }}{{content.name}}{{/link-to}}</td></tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: error]

[image]

## **U P D A T E S**

my issue got resolved by changing 
`{{#link-to 'category.product' category content }}` in my accordion view to 
`{{#link-to product' category content }}`

but as per ember guides 
[Ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)
 I can pass two model like this sample code

```
<p>
  {{#link-to 'photo.comment' 5 primaryComment}}
    Main Comment for the Next Photo
  {{/link-to}}
</p>
```

i dont understand if its because my router hierarchy. but in any case i think it should give some nice error. I an a noob wonder what experts think on this

Comment: what's in accordian js

Comment: accordion js consist of my bootstrap accordion. I got the code working I have updated the question still i dont understand why it worked this way

Comment: I would change the title to something about link-to. Also it you posted an error so "Ember fails without error" isn't exactly accurate. Something like "Link-to cannot find route"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `'product'` in your link-to instead of `'category.product'`.
This is because in `MyApp.Router.map()` you made product a resource, not a route.
Resources' route names are unprefixed, whereas routes' route names are prefixed with their parent resource.
See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources